# ¿Conexión remota ip dinamica?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Este es mi problema: Tengo una aplicación `Winforms` que se instalará en dos pcs.

¿Cómo sería la cadena de conexión en el cliente para que se conecte a la pc servidor si la pc servidor tiene una ip dinámica?

Comment: Si la ip del servidor es dinámica la unica solución es que éste publique su ip en algun sitio en el que el cliente la pueda consultar. Puedes hacerlo de forma manual o usar algun servicio de dns dinamica como por ejemplo, [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/)

Comment: ¿Están dentro de la misma LAN o es a través de Internet?

Comment: La IP puede cambiar, el nombre del servidor no.

Comment: si, estan dentro de la misma LAN. Si estan dentro de la misma LAN, solo necesitaria colocar el nombre del servidor?